# How do you see what an http request contains

Tags: django

I'm using a **django framework** for my assignment. I need to view what an http request object contains. `print(request)` is obviously not working. If I can see the object like in a json structure it would've been a huge help to understand what it would look like and what are the values it contains.

Comment: you can add a breakpoint and see and by the way you can see `request.GET` to see what you got by get request  `request.POST` to see what you have got in post request it is a dictionary

Comment: `prinln(json.dumps(request)`

Comment: Django's HTTPRequest object is documented here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/ and the source code is of course available here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/_modules/django/http/request/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what type of request is `GET` or `POST`. You can find  `print(request.GET)` or in `print(request.POST)` which is of `<type 'dict'>` and you can access data simply by `request.GET.get("somedata")` will return `None` if not found

**Note**: If you want to see attributes of request object you can do `print(dir(request))` and you can do that on any object.

For more quick help you can do `help(request)` in python shell.

Comment: Those are `QueryDict`s not `dict`s, and they only contain part of the request.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to see what `request` contains (and more to that - any other object in python) is to use simple:

`print(request.__dict__)`